# Stripping email addresses from arbitrary file

Tags: regex, sed, awk

What's the best way to get user@host.com combinations from a large fileset?

I assume that sed/awk can do this, but I'm not very familiar with regexp.

We have a file i.e., Staff_data.txt that houses more than just emails, and would like to strip the rest of the data, and gather only the email addresses (i.e., h@south.com)

I figured the easiest way would be via sed/awk in a terminal, but seeing as how complex regexp can be, I'd appreciate some guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You want `grep` here not `sed` or `awk`. For example to display all emails from the domain `south.com`:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*@south\.com ' file
```

Comment: You'd need to anchor that and escape RE metachar "." or it'd match on "john@south com" if the text "john@south common drive" appeared in the file and it'd fail to find ".net", etc. addresses and it'd find many more false-positives.

Comment: In the very vague question posted I see no reference to any .net addresses besides I qualified the answer with "emails from the domain south.com". Okay, I should have escaped the period. Remember the question is for arbitrary files so a 'perfect' answer is unobtainable, this is the real world approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat embarrassing but apparently working script I wrote a few years ago to do this job:

```
# Get rid of any Message-Id line like this:
#   Message-ID: <AANLkTinSDG_dySv_oy_7jWBD=QWiHUMpSEFtE-cxP6Y1@mail.gmail.com>
#
# Change any character that can't be in an email address to a space.
#
# Print just the character strings that look like email addresses.
#
# Drop anything with multple "@"s and change any domain names (i.e.
# the part after the "@") to all lower case as those are not case-sensitive.
#
# If we have a local mail box part (i.e. the part before the "@") that's
# a mix of upper/lower and another that's all lower, keep them both. Ditto
# for multiple versions of mixed case since we don't know which is correct.
#
# Sort uniquely.

cat "$@" |
awk '!/^Message-ID:/' |
awk '{gsub(/[^-_.@[:alnum:]]+/," ")}1' |
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /.+@.+[.][[:alpha:]]+$/) print $i}' |
awk '
  BEGIN   { FS=OFS="@" }
  NF != 2 { printf "Badly formatted %s skipped.\n",$0 | "cat>&2"; next }
  { $2=tolower($2); print }
' |
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' |
sort -u
```

It's not pretty, but it seems to be robust.

Comment: I was young and stupid. Now I'm old and lazy. Oddly enough, I don't recall a period in between.